# Why is HCl not considered to have hydrogen bonding?

Tags: electronegativity, dipole, hydrogen-bond

A molecule that has hydrogen bonding **usually** follows these two premises.

> 1.) There is a hydrogen atom involved
>
> 2.) Hydrogen must be bonded to a highly electronegative element which are nitrogen ($\ce{N}$), fluorine ($\ce{F}$) and oxygen ($\ce{O}$).

Seeing that both oxygen and chlorine have a small difference in their electronegativity (oxygen being roughly **3.5** and chlorine being roughly **3.0**), why does chlorine in a hydrogen chloride molecule ($\ce{HCl}$) have a dipole-dipole interaction, while the oxygen in a water molecule ($\ce{H2O}$) causes the water molecule to have a stronger form of dipole-dipole interaction called hydrogen bonding? I do not understand this since **chlorine is just as electronegative as oxygen and nitrogen**?

**Edit**: I should also added that nitrogen and chlorine have the same EN value (**3.0**)

Comment: [Related](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/5503/what-exactly-is-hydrogen-bonding-and-why-cant-it-exist-with-atoms-other-than-f). Short answer: $\ce{Cl}$ is too large.

Comment: @Asker123 Could you go a little more in depth?

Comment: Also, check out the example from [this answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/51920/41328).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very, very [related](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/5503/what-exactly-is-hydrogen-bonding-and-why-cant-it-exist-with-atoms-other-than-f?lq=1). Check it for a more in depth answer.

Well, first-of-all you need to understand that the $\ce{H}$ bonding isn't actually bonding. It is just a covalent attraction. Also since $\ce{Cl}$ is larger than $\ce{N}$, $\ce{F}$ and $\ce{O}$ it does not make a strong $\ce{H}$ bond. **The size of the $\ce{Cl}$ makes the dipole-dipole attraction weaker**. However $\ce{N}$, $\ce{F}$ and $\ce{O}$ are smaller and thus have an $\ce{H}$ bond.

Although in reality, compared to other covalently bonded structures, $\ce{HCl}$ has a very strong covalent bond.

Answer (score 1):

Despite its electronegativity, size of chlorine atom is large and hence, electron density of chlorine is not sufficient to form Hydrogen Bonding.
Hence, HCl does not have hydrogen Bonding.