# Can chlorine form hydrogen bonds?

Tags: halides, hydrogen-bond

My question is simple, If chlorine ($\ce{_17Cl^35^.^5}$) and nitrogen ($\ce{_7N^14}$) have similar values of electronegativity, and chlorine has way more lone pairs than nitrogen, what prevents it from forming hydrogen bonds ?

(other than in chloral dihydrate $\ce{CCl3CH(OH)2)}$

Comment: related http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/31591/why-is-hcl-not-considered-to-have-hydrogen-bonding?s=1|0.2701

Comment: Or again http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/21773/why-is-hydrogen-bonding-generally-defined-to-include-only-three-period-two-eleme may be a better dupe.

Comment: i guess its more likely to be classified as a dupe of the second, although it never came up when i gave the title. P.S: How do i assign it as the second one's duplicate @Mithoron

Comment: With [newest Stack Exchange™ technology](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291824/gold-tag-badge-holders-and-moderators-can-now-edit-duplicate-links) it is possible to mark a post as a duplicate of both questions. You guys can close it as a dupe of one post first, and then myself or another mod can edit the duplicate list.

Comment: sure, ill do it immediately, thanks(P.S: since thanks comments arent allowed, will delete this comment too.lol) @orthocresol

Comment: Don't worry about it, thanks comments are perfectly fine and we like having them here, because it means people are being nice to each other. We just clear them as we go along (once they've served their purpose).

Comment: @Supernova https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3071/searching-guidelines-for-newbie

Comment: Thanks again, will do accordingly from next time @Mithoron

Comment: You can come to chat http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3229/the-periodic-table for some tips/talking/stuff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nitrogen is equally electronegative as chlorine but also more **compact**.  Whether you consider hydrogen bonding as purely electrostatic or having a covalent character (*The lone pair on atom X overlaps the molecular orbital in the H-Y bond of an adjacent molecule, thus partially delocalizing the bond*), the more compact structure of nitrogen offers an advantage.