Dipole-dipole vs London dispersion forces for deducing melting and boiling points
To determine the melting and boiling points of compounds, London dispersion forces are typically compared. However, why are the polarity and dipole-dipole forces ignored?
For instance, $\ce{HI}$ has a higher melting point in comparison to $\ce{HCl}$, as $\ce{HI}$'s London dispersion forces are stronger due to the larger size of the iodide anion. But this also indicates that $\ce{HI}$ has a smaller electronegativity difference, which would translate to a weaker dipole-dipole interaction. However, shouldn't we give a higher priority to the dipole-dipole interaction over London dispersion forces as they are much stronger?
Furthermore, $\ce{H}$-bonding, which is a type of dipole-dipole interaction, is prioritised if present in the compound. So when should I prioritise each?


H-bonding, which is a type of dipole-dipole interaction

H-bonds are not dipole-dipole interactions. Electrostatic interactions, of which dipole-dipole are one type, contribute to H-bonding. H-bonds involve electron donation and are therefore related to the class referred to as dipolar or dative covalent. Dipole-dipole interactions can lead to molecular alignment and mutual attraction but not electron sharing. Other properties of H-bonds that distinguish them: directionality, a strong dependence on distance between donor-acceptor, and strength. H-bonds require close proximity to allow orbital overlap, whereas dipolar interactions persist over longer distances (albeit with a strong distance dependence). Additional properties of H-bonds are mentioned in this post.

But this also indicates that HI has a smaller electronegativity difference, which would translate to a weaker dipole-dipole interaction.

Electronegativity expresses the extent to which electronic charge is transferred between atoms and can influence the strength of intermolecular interactions by distorting the charge distribution, but the partial transfer of electron charge to large halogen atoms will not appreciably alter the latter's total electronic charge. The charge distribution is dominated by the halogen nuclei and large diffuse electron clouds. The H atoms are wedged in as small passengers in a bus full of giants.

You look at everything: dipole-dipole, H-bonding, and dispersion. You prioritize them in the order of strength: H-bonding > other dipole interactions > dispersion forces, but you also consider which one is the most widespread. Naturally, this means that you prioritize them when they are possible. So why then, do we not consider the supposed hydrogen bonds in HI and HCl?
Dipole interactions of any kind are complex. I would recommend you check out the IUPAC's requirements for a hydrogen bond here. Though this is quite simplified, one could say there are two major criteria for H-bonding to happen: (1) a large electronegativity difference between H and the bound atom; (2) the ability for the molecule to hold on to the hydrogen while H-bonding. Both HI and HCl satisfy condition (1) — that condition is actually the easiest to satisfy. Condition (2) is more difficult. As stated by the IUPAC,

The length of the X–H bond usually increases on hydrogen bond formation leading to a red shift in the infrared X–H stretching frequency and an increase in the infrared absorption cross-section for the X–H stretching vibration. The greater the lengthening of the X–H bond in X–H···Y,   the stronger is the H···Y bond. Simultaneously, new vibrational modes associated with the formation of the H···Y bond are generated.

HI has a very very large H—I bond length at about 165pm, which is larger than most C—C bonds. Hydrogen bonding in HI would only increase this bond length, resulting in the loss of the proton. Similarly, in HCl; the chloride is too large to accomodate the H-bonding without losing the proton. There are no other dipole-dipole interactions possible in either molecule aside from H-bonding, so we resort to dispersion forces, in which the molecule with more electrons always has stronger forces of attraction. Now, those dipole forces do exist in these molecules, but they are so incredibly small that dispersion forces are always larger except in HF, where hydrogen bonding does exist. I would also recommend reading this answer by Orthocresol to a related question.

Well, I recommend https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/35488/is-hydrogen-bonding-a-type-of-dipole-dipole-interaction https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/101119/9961

@Mithoron Thanks. Yes, hydrogen bonds have some covalent character and said H-bonds would be more frequent in HCl compared to HI. Some specific molecules can also H-bond to both. Regardless, these seem to be small (relatively) interactions compared to dispersion forces, so it seems more productive to look at those compared to H-bonding in this case.
