# How the attraction takes place between a hydrogen atom and the acceptor atom in a hydrogen bond

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, bond, hydrogen-bond

In hydrogen bonds present in water,does the hydrogen atom attracts to the lone pair of electrons present on the oxygen atom or to its partial negative charge? If former is the case are there any examples in which the acceptor atom do not have a lone pair of electrons but it attracts hydrogen because of its partial negative charge. 
I got confused because I saw in YouTube video where the definition of hydrogen bond was given as: A hydrogen bond is a weak bond between a partially positive hydrogen atom and a partially negative electronegative atom

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/5503/what-exactly-is-hydrogen-bonding-and-does-it-really-need-fluorine-oxygen-or-n

Comment: Well, there has to be an orbital donating a bit of electron density, so that hydrogen bond gets some covalent character.